# my setup for C# application whit Database Don't run on target machin

Tags: c#, installation, setuptools, setup-project

When I make setup whit ***visual studio installer*** whit **no prerequisites** and test it on windows 7, I see this error

[image]

then I add this prerequisites : **SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB**
and see that error again.

I add :  **SQL Server 2012 Express**,**SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB**,**.NET Framework 4.5.2**

when I build it, I see this warning :

```
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'PlayerList' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'PlayerList' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: PlayerList, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\ChiKo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PlayerList\PlayerList\Debug\PlayerList.msi'...
WARNING: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX452\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'.
WARNING: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'SQL Server 2012 Express' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE'.
WARNING: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'SQL Server 2012 Express' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.EXE'.
Packaging file 'Icons.ico'...
Packaging file 'Db.mdf'...
Packaging file 'Db_log.ldf'...
Packaging file 'PlayerList.exe'...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

i build setup, but **not work in target system**.
I don't know **which prerequisites needed for make setup of my app** ?
**I have one simple C# app having database**(Service-based Database)(*.mdf).

Comment: you'r error tell me about SQL Server Instance not installed

Comment: If it's your setup that's failing, then you need to say what exactly you are doing. It looks you have a custom action that is attempting to connect to a SQL instance, but I'm guessing.

Comment: I agree with Phil. The original error looks as if you are attempting to connect to a particular instance on the local machine but instance name does not exist. Did you configure the install of SQL Express to create the proper instance name rather than the default MSSQLSERVER? Also make sure that your SQL Server instance is running in services.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add SQL Server Express to your installer. According to your error your c# application can't connect to database because of you don't have SQL Server on target machine.

Please try to put your installer file at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

I'm using "**Visual Studio 2015**". In our application we use "**SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB**".

Know when I make setup and test my application in target machine, I install "SQL **"Server 2012 Express LocalDB"** in the target system.

In **"SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB"** we have **"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"** but in **SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB** we dont have it.